# Convert any object to pretty HTML in java

Tags: java, html

How can I convert a given object (in a generic way with reflection) to pretty printable HTML?
What ready made library do you recommend that does this? I need support for simple nested objects (as long as they don't create loops in the object graph).

I tried to convert it to JSON, but [DefaultPrettyPrinter](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.5.1/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/impl/DefaultPrettyPrinter.html) is not HTML friendly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could relatively easily write your own library for doing so.  [Here's some example code](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) that you could modify relatively easily to show html.  Another option is to display the JSON inside a code tag in html.  One final option is to use ReflectionToStringBuilder in [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and again show the result inside of a code tag in html.  Using apache commons is probably no better than the json format however.

Answer (score 8):

You could create an XSLT style for the XML output of [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) on your object.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in a two step process:

1. Convert object to JSON using any library of your preference, e.g. [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```java
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

2. Convert JSON string to HTML using a ready-made solution, such as [json2html](http://json2html.com/) or write your own implementation. Have a look at the [visualizer](http://visualizer.json2html.com/) demo. You can also use the open-source [jsoneditor](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/) which has an ad-supported [online version](https://jsoneditoronline.org/).